# ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi for uwsgi

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi for my Django(version =1.4) project, but there's an error if I run

```
uwsgi --ini django.ini
```

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

but I could import django.core.wsgi as follows:

```
>>> import django.core.wsgi
```

the django.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/path/to/my/app
module=app.wsgi:application
master=True
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000
socket=127.0.0.1:9000
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Do you have a local `django.py` file at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use virtualenv try to add `home` to django.ini:

```
home=/path/to/venv/
```

To test it through web browser:

```
uwsgi --ini django.ini --protocol=http
```

Comment: where is the "django.ini" ?

Comment: look at the [doc](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-django)

Comment: Receiving : No module named 'encodings'

Answer (score 26):

If you installed gunicorn on both `sudo apt-get install gunicorn` and `(venv) pip install gunicorn`, use `sudo apt-get remove gunicorn` and restart your virtual environment. This way, it worked for me.

Comment: It is working, Me too first installed using apt-get install gunicorn and then with pip. I removed sudo apt-get remove. It is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Wow this worked for me, THANKS! I reinstalled Gunicorn using pip3 install gunicorn instead of sudo apt-get install gunicorn

Answer (score 24):

The error `ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi` generally arises when uwsgi tries reading the wsgi.py file, and comes to the line:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

It can't find this these modules because Django is not installed, or if it is installed, it is not in PYTHONPATH.

If your project is in a virtualenv and Django is only installed in this virtualenv, somehow the path to the Django modules are not in the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), and thus Python can't find it.

If you are curious, you can insert the following code into the `wsgi.py` file, and see the PYTHONPATH:

```
import os
print '===== sys.path / PYTHONPATH ====='
for k in sorted(os.environ.keys()):
    v = os.environ[k]
    print ('%-30s %s' % (k,v[:70]))
```

If you run a local version of uwsgi, installed in the virtualenv, then the path will be set correct, but if you run a global version of uwsgi it will normally not have the PYTHONPATH set correctly.

You can tell uWSGI the path to the virtualenv, and it will figure out the correct PYTHONPATH. Just use the `--virtualenv` command line argument, eg:

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --module wsgi --virtualenv /home/jdoe/myvirtualenv
```

(The following arguments does exactly the same as --virtualenv: --venv, --home, -H)

### Surprisingly, setting $VIRTUAL_ENV has no effect on PYTHONPATH

Strangely enough, if you don't use the --virtualenv argument, the environment variable `$VIRTUAL_ENV` will be set correctly. Test this by inserting into wsgi.py:

```
print os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
```

This will print:

```
/home/jdoe/myvirtualenv
```

But the PYTHONPATH is *not* set correctly, and does not include anything from the virtualenv.

I can't explain why this is.

Comment: The `--virtualenv` was the key! Thanks for the perfect analysis @mads-skjern

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I installed the Django application and everything else for Python3, but the uwsgi was using Python2. Just check the log while running uwsgi whether it is using Python2 or Python3, and reinstall uwsgi if it is not consistent. Look for the line similar to below line in uwsgi startup log.

`Python version: 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:31:36)  [GCC 4.8.4]`
VS
`Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you accepted the answer which mentions `virtualenv`, it seems that you use it. In this case make sure that `django` is installed in your `virtualenv` directory (say `venv`).

You can separately install it from `pip` under `virtualenv` or manually create a symbolic link (if you are on Unix-like system) to `venv`'s site-packages

```
ln -s /usr/path_to_django venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I created the virtual environment in a shared folder of virtualbox which didn't allow symbolic links. I recieved some errors but everything seemed to work so I continued until I got this error. The problem was solved when I recreated my virtual environment, made sure there were no errors and pointed uwsgi to the folder.