# ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi (ubuntu)

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, importerror

I am following this guide to configure apache for my django web application:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration

I have installed [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip), [mod_wsgi-express](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) (the *new* way) and [mod_wsgi for apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/installing-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-12-04) on an ubuntu 15.10 server using:

```
pip install Django
pip install mod_wsgi
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Next I have added the below to: **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/user/mysite:/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /home/user/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

But when I start apache I get the below error:

```
[Sat Mar 26 12:10:06.876025 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10622:tid 139806697674496] [client 217.40.250.17:52124]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Mar 26 12:10:06.876057 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10622:tid 139806697674496] [client 217.40.250.17:52124] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

But that module indeed exists in the path I have supplied in **WSGIPythonPath** above:

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core $ cat wsgi.py
import django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
```

And:

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ ll
total 24
drwx------  6 user user 4096 Mar 24 22:25 ./
drwx------  3 user user 4096 Mar 20 20:56 ../
drwxrwxr-x 17 user user 4096 Mar 24 22:25 django/
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 Mar 24 22:25 Django-1.9.4.dist-info/
drwxrwxr-x  5 user user 4096 Mar 20 20:59 mod_wsgi/
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 Mar 20 20:59 mod_wsgi-4.4.22.egg-info/
```

I also tried to validate the version of python the mod_wsgi module was build against:

```
 /usr/lib/apache2/modules $ ldd mod_wsgi.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe50f31000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f376fbc2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f376f9a4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f376f5d9000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f376f3bf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f376f1bb000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f376efb7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f376ecaf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005609838b3000)
```

So it appears it was build against Python 2.7 which is the same version Django is being installed under.

**So why does apache fail to load my application/django?**

Comment: have you check these links? :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194859/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-for-uwsgi
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927345/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-apache-virtualenv-aws-wsgi

Comment: Yes read both those posts but they don't describe that you actually need to change permissions on the folders containing django and the web application. I only found one reference describing that, see my updated question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If your solution is your answer to the problem, then please create a real answer, and provide an adequate explanation of why it works. SO will let you select the solution after a timeout. Please do NOT put the solution in your question, as that's not what questions are for. Also, please don't add "Edit:" or "Update:" tags to the question/answer as you change it. We can see what has been revised. Instead add the information where it would have been initially if you'd added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on:
http://www.webforefront.com/django/setupapachewebserverwsgi.html

the **www-data** user (user running apache folder) must have read access to the folder containing the django installation. I just did a test where I copied the django installation and my web application to: **/var/www/test** and changed the permission for that folder:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/test
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /var/www/test
```

and the application now loads.

Comment: chmod g+rwx does not grants only read access, it gives EVERY (including write) access to the group www-data... isn't that INSECURE?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error just now when I was trying to set up my Django, Nginx and WSGI according to this tutorial: https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

When I typed in the command: `uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi`

I get the error:

> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application ImportError: No
>   module named django.core.wsgi

It made no sense to me because when I entered the python shell in my virtualenv and imported the module, it worked perfect.

However, I found this tutorial to be useful in getting rid of the error: https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module project.wsgi --virtualenv /path/to/virtualenv
```

Typing in the path to your virtualenv causes WSGI to find the module it was missing.

You can find the path to the virtualenv by typing in `$ECHO virtualenv` in your command prompt / terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Reason being that I had installed gunicorn via apt, which was then running in the system-wide Python 2 installation, instead of my venv.

Fixed it by uninstalling the system gunicorn, and then activating my venv, and installing gunicorn to the venv using pip install gunicorn. Then it worked straight away.