# ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: django, uwsgi, django-wsgi

I am getting this error while deploying django project on uwsgi and nginx server
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi for uwsgi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194859/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-for-uwsgi)

Comment: I am getting error while testing  
uwsgi --http ip:8080 --home /home/prithvi/Env/curanest --chdir /home/prithvi/curanest -w curanest.wsgi

Answer (score -1):

1. Check Django Version
2. Make sure settings.py is loaded in to env properly.