# django + virtualenv + gunicorn - No module named django.core.wsgi?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn

I have `gunicorn` installed inside my virtual env:

```
$ pip install gunicorn
Collecting gunicorn
  Using cached gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: gunicorn
Successfully installed gunicorn-19.7.1
```

But when I try run my app with it:

```
$ gunicorn helloapp.wsgi
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1963] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1963] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1963)
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1963] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1967] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1967
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1967] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 384, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/helloapp/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1967] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1967)
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1963] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-05-18 22:42:36 +0000] [1963] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

What I have done wrong?

This is my app structure:[image]

Any ideas?

This is my requirments.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.11.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
```

**EDIT:**

```
(env) xxx@xxx-desktop:/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp$ which gunicorn
/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/gunicorn

(env) xxx@xxx-desktop:/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp$ which pip
/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/pip
```

Comment: What's the output of `which gunicorn`, `which pip`, and `pip freeze`...there might be different Pythons or environments that the commands are hitting

Comment: @NickT please see my edit above.

Comment: can you share the full path of your wsgi File!?

Comment: @DhiaTN it's `/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/helloapp/wsgi.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should actually run it as follow:

```
gunicorn helloapp.wsgi:application
```

- Basic usage of gunicorn:

`gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE`

Where `APP_MODULE` is of the pattern `$(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME)`

Comment: Did you activate your virtualenv? because it looks like it does not find the django modules.

Comment: but it is strange that it works on my production server. not on my local server

Comment: check here it may be a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/14196195/5658350

Comment: got it running now after rebooting my local machine. not sure it is django or python issue. they are just annoying!

Comment: Explicitly specifying "application" is unnecessary.  See http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#django.  That makes this answer basically a non-answer.

Answer (score 12):

It might not be the case for this particular question However I encountered a similar issue and was led here by google. So I place this answer here in the hope to be useful for others.

The problem for me was that gunicorn was being ran by a `globally installed package` not the one that was installed in the virtual environment. To make sure that whether this is the case for you or not, just simply run the `which gunicorn` and check it is coming from your virtualenv bin directory. If it is not coming from your virtual env bin directory follow these steps:

1. Deactivated the env.

   - `deactivate env`
2. Uninstalled the globally installed gunicron

   - `pip uninstall gunicorn`
3. Activate the env. [ I use virtualenvwrapper for virtualenv management and I recommend you to do so. ]

   - `workon env`

Now gunicorn should work as expected.

Comment: I ran into this issue and this answer fixed it for me! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. In my case I was able to override the global gunicorn by installing gunicorn in my venv with `pip3 install gunicorn`. Then I ran `which gunicorn` and verified that gunicorn was pointing to my venv's copy.

Answer (score 9):

I have same issue and I solved it by removing gunicorn which installed with system package manager(`apt-get` etc).

`apt-get` installing gunicorn to **site-packages of python2** and `pip` installing `Django` to **site-packages of python3**. So Gunicorn and Django not in same site-packages directory. So gunicorn cannot find django. Insalling Gunicorn and Django in same package dir should solve the problem.

Comment: Confusingly, this was necessary for me, even though `which gunicorn` pointed to the `venv` version. Just having the global installation messed things up, even though it shouldn't have been used in the first place.

Comment: Gunicorn for python3 is available as deb. Try `apt install gunicorn3`

Answer (score 5):

In `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`, make sure your Working Directory is pointing to your app directory.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myproject
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out here and elsewhere, the root of the problem as indidcated by the error message is that `gunicorn` cannot find the django modules.  The question then becomes why that is the case and there can be many different reasons.  In my case on a Ubuntu bionic host without virtualenv it was due to the fact that I had installed python3-django and gunicorn (the latter being a python2 package).

The solution was to install python3-gunicorn, remove gunicorn and run gunicorn as `gunicorn3`.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong directory:**

> check your current directory then `cd` to the right directory before
>   calling.

**Example:**

*Incorrect:*

```
~/project_name/main$ gunicorn3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 main.wsgi:application
```

*Correct:*

```
~/project_name/main$ cd ..
~/project_name$ gunicorn3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 main.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using poetry and pyenv. In my case it turns out the gunicorn instance that I was running was referencing a system level installation, as opposed to the one installed in the virtual environment. I figured this out by running `which gunicorn` and comparing it to the output of `pyenv which gunicorn`.

What solved it for me was doing

`$(pyenv which gunicorn) <app_name>.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of the answers above and another solution. I deactivated virtual env and Installed Django, then I activated it and ran the command like this: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`